# What is the trend in hydration entropy of alkali metal ions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

Is there a trend in alkali metal ion hydration entropy?

There's much talk of hydration enthalpy, but I have a hard time finding information about the change in entropy.

Am I right in thinking that Li$^+$ would have a more negative $\Delta S^o_{hyd}$ than Cs$^+$ because more water ligands will be ordered around it, due to it's higher charge density?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. The following is a plot of the hydration enthalpy versus row in the Periodic Table. Data was extracted from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_ions_in_aqueous_solution), not the primary source (Ref 1).

Your thinking is right. The hydration entropy is evidently negative due to structuring of water (including loss of rotational degrees of freedom), becoming *less* negative for the larger ions (smallest loss of entropy for the cesium cation).

[image]

*References*

1. Burgess, John (1978). Metal Ions in Solution. Chichester: Ellis Horwood. ISBN 978-0-85312-027-8.